# Count number of rows and sum up a field of all tables in all relevant schemas with a readonly connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sum

We have a rather complex database setup which involves 500 schemas. Most of these schemas contain a certain table. This table contains a certain number of rows and those rows contain a size field.

I need to iterate the schemas, detect those schemas that contain the relevant table and count the number of rows and sum up the size field.

The correct SQL statement for one schema looks like this:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(SUM((ceil(SMART_REPOSITORY_LOGICAL_FILE.SRLF_SIZE / 4096)*4096)) / (1024*1024),0) AS
    "Volume in MB",
    COUNT(*) AS "number of files"
FROM
    SCHEMA_XYZ.SMART_REPOSITORY_LOGICAL_FILE
WHERE
    SMART_REPOSITORY_LOGICAL_FILE.SRLF_IS_DIRECTORY = 'N'
```

How could I run this over all schemas that contain the table `SMART_REPOSITORY_LOGICAL_FILE` ?

I already tried [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704808/get-counts-of-all-tables-in-a-schema) available here that involve some XML magic but obviously I don't have the permission to use those calls because I am rejected. I also can not use approaches that involve writing to the schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss Tony Andrew's solution @ [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705045/7366100) ?

Here's a dbfiddle example based on Tony's solution: [find count and sum from same table w/ different schemas](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc42e4936d5b18f9e08c84eb27dc3859)

For the sake of this example I'll setup a second AUDIT_ACTIONS table:

```
create table AUDIT_ACTIONS as (select * from SYS.AUDIT_ACTIONS where ACTION <= 50)
```

Create a table to store our results in:

```
create table results(owner varchar(100), table_name varchar(100), row_count integer, audit_sum integer);
```

Some minor tweaks to Tony's solution:

```
declare
    v_count integer;
    v_sum   integer;
begin
    for t in (select table_name, owner from all_tables
              where table_name = 'AUDIT_ACTIONS') 
    loop
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*), sum(ACTION) from ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name
              into v_count, v_sum;
          insert into results (owner, table_name, row_count, audit_sum)
          values (t.owner, t.table_name, v_count, v_sum) ;
    end loop;        
end ;
/
```

And the results:

```
select * from results;
```

> ```
> OWNER                       | TABLE_NAME    | ROW_COUNT | AUDIT_SUM
> :-------------------------- | :------------ | --------: | --------:
> FIDDLE_QPLKSTJBEESOQLZCONZA | AUDIT_ACTIONS |        51 |      1275
> SYS                         | AUDIT_ACTIONS |       180 |     18451
> ```

NOTE: The non-SYS OWNER(SCHEMA) will change with each dbfiddle run.

Comment: Doesn't this only use the current schema ? I need to scan all schemas. Besides that I am not allowed to write to the database, so CREATE is forbidden to me. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Now I understood that my interpretation of `all_tables` was wrong and that it contains all tables of all schemas. I modified the example above and did a simple `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ...` and left out the `INSERT INTO` part because as I mentioned I am not allowed to write anywhere. Is it possible to run the `for` and output the `SELECT` results to the screen in a `UNION` way ?

Comment: create the results table as a global temporary table; or are you saying this isn't doable either? as for the UNION question, while you could use the for loop to build up a large multi-UNION select (in a variable), I'm not sure about the limits on how large the variable could get (we're talking about upwards of 500 select statements UNIONed together, right?)

Comment: 505 at present, to be exact ;-) The server running the database must not be altered in any way, you should consider the connection "read only"

Comment: so convert `results` to a record/table variable; though how you send the contents back to your client will depend on what you're using as your client (and with that we're pushing the limits of my PL/SQL knowledge without me doing a lot of googling)

Comment: Thanks, I think I will simply convert this to Java and do the Iteration there